# How to deploy only specified code files with TdsGlobal.config.user

Tags: tds, deployment, web-deploy

I'm working on a project that uses TDS. The VS Solution has this file `TdsGlobal.config.user`, where the `SitecoreWebUrl` and `SitecoreDeployFolder` are configured.

When I use the `Deploy Solution` option, it deploys all the code files to the deployment folder.
But it deploys all the dlls including the ones that already exist in the instance webroot (e.g. Sitecore's, Microsoft etc).

How do I configure to deploy only the project files. e.g:
MyProject.*.*.dll, AnyThirdParty.dll  etc

Here is the TdsGlobal.config.user file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">    
    <RecursiveDeployAction>Ignore</RecursiveDeployAction>
    <SitecoreWebUrl>https://myproject.dev.local</SitecoreWebUrl>
    <InstallSitecoreConnector>True</InstallSitecoreConnector>
    <DisableFileDeployment>False</DisableFileDeployment>
    <LightningDeployMode>True</LightningDeployMode>
    <EnableContainerDeployment>False</EnableContainerDeployment>
    <ConnectorTimeoutSeconds>120</ConnectorTimeoutSeconds>
    <SitecoreAccessGuid>9f29d2bc-4f59-45ce-a680-551946d73129</SitecoreAccessGuid>
    <SitecoreDeployFolder>C:\out\MyProject.Deploy</SitecoreDeployFolder>   
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">    
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation you can skip the deployment of certain assemblies like this. Here is the description.

> When deploying to Sitecore, Sitecore TDS can skip the deployment of certain assemblies. These assemblies may be referenced by one or more projects in the solution. Excluding/including static assemblies from the build will reduce the size of the packages Sitecore TDS generates and improve deployment time. By default, Sitecore TDS excludes assemblies beginning with “Sitecore.”. Selecting Exclude from the drop down will cause Sitecore TDS to skip these files and not add them to the deployment. Selecting Include from the drop down will only include the assemblies listed and cause Sitecore TDS to skip all other assemblies.

https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html

Comment: Is that not a config to be specified in TdsGlobal.config. Should that be done for each TDS project in the solution?

Comment: @Qwerty Not fully sure about this. But as per this article, it is stating the same as I mentioned above. Please have a look.

https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/20/excluding-sitecore-assemblies-from-deployment/